# USGS Earth Explorer: Bulk Download from metadata export

Tags: usgs, earth-explorer

I want to create a large bulk download order for Landsat Level-3 FSCA data. My search returns ~6700 results, but as far as I can tell I can only add one page of results (10) at a time. Is there a way to add all results to a bulk download order? I exported the metadata to csv ...